# Track when javascript object levels up during recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have a 3 level depth object, with the same structured childs:

```
var data = {
0:{"level":1,
   "data": {
    0:{"level":2,
     "data": {
        0:{"level":3,
        "data": null},
        1:{"level":3,
        "data": null}
      }
    },
    1:{"level":2,
     "data":{ 
        0:{"level":3,
         "data": null},
        1:{"level":3,
         "data": null}
      }
    } 
   }
}}
```

and a recurstion function:

```
$.each(data, function(k,v){
    rfunc(k,v)
});
function rfunc(key, val) { 
    console.log(val.level)
    if ( val.data ) {
        $.each(val.data, function(key, val) {
            rfunc(key, val) 
        });
    }
}
```

which consoles, as expected:
1 
2
3
3
2
3
3
Help me please with the way i can track when programm moves back level up to "2"

Thanks for attention!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? When control returns after the `$.each` loop, you know that you are one level up again.

Comment: this is templating utility, what do you mean "When control returns" - how to code it?

Comment: I mean when the call to `$.each` returns, then you are back up one level. Just do whatever you want to do after the `$.each`.

Comment: but how to track at what level i am - the object structure is the same for every level, i mean what how to check if i'm travelling up or down?

Comment: Before the `$.each` you just travelled down. After the `$.each` you travelled up. I.e. before you make the next recursive call, you travelled down, after the recursive call you travelled up. The recursive call goes one level down, so when the call returns, you went up again. Doesn't this make sense? Maybe this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/7f3Gk/.

Comment: Please, shorten your code to `$.each(val.data, rfunc)`

Answer (score 0):

solution using one each(recursion): http://jsfiddle.net/px3KT/

```
var data = {
0:{"level":1,
   "data": {
    0:{"level":2,
     "data": {
        0:{"level":3,
        "data": null},
        1:{"level":3,
        "data": null}
      }
    },
    1:{"level":2,
     "data":{ 
        0:{"level":3,
         "data": null},
        1:{"level":3,
         "data": null}
      }
    } 
   }
}}

function recurseData(obj,level){
    console.log(level);
    if(obj){
         $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
            var level = val.level;
            var data_obj = val.data;
            recurseData(data_obj,level); 
        });   
    }
}

recurseData(data);
```